# 2 warnings: 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int **' and different types for formal and actual parameter 3

Tags: c, arrays, warnings

I wrote a code which supposes to remove duplicate elements in array of ints without sorting it.

For that task, I wrote a function named 
'removeDuplicateElements', which gets an array and its string, and returns a new array dynamically allocated, which is actually the originial array with removal of its all duplicates elements.
This function also returns by reference the size of the new array.

I also used in my code functions which build a dynamic array and print it.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printArray(int* arr, int size);
int* buildArray(int size);
int* removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int *newSize);

void main()
{
    int size;
    int *newSize;
    int *arr;
    int *newArr;

    printf("please enter a number for the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\nenter %d numbers: ", size);
    arr = buildArray(size);
    printf("\nthe array after removing the duplicate elements  is: ");
    newArr = removeDuplicateElements(arr, size, &newSize);
    size = *newSize;
    printArray(newArr, size);
    free(newArr);
    free(arr);
}

void printArray(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}


int* buildArray(int size)
{
    int i;
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    if (!arr)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    return arr;
}

int* removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int *newSize)
{
    int *newArr;
    int count = size, i, j;

    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i!=j)
            {
                count--;
                break;
            }
    newArr = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    count = 1;
    newArr[0] = arr[0];

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j] && i!=j)
                    break;
            else if (j == size - 1)
                newArr[count++] = arr[i];
        }

    *newSize = count;
    return newArr;
}
```

**Now, when I run this code - I get to two following warnings:**

```
warning C4047: 'function': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int **'
warning C4024: 'removeDuplicateElements': different types for formal and actual parameter 3
```

I have tried to get help by qeustions with similar problem, but I still dont understand what is wrong  and why I get those warnings.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The compiler tells you what's wrong, you define `removeDuplicateElements` to take `int *` as it's 3rd parameter, but when you call it, you pass it an `int **`.

Comment: Just declare `int newSize;` instead of `int *newSize;`

Answer (score -1):

You are passing `int**` for 3rd argument for `removeDuplicateElements` but receiving `int*`.

```
int *newSize;
newArr = removeDuplicateElements(arr, size, &newSize);
```

your prototype,

```
int* removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int *newSize)
```

should be

```
int* removeDuplicateElements(int *arr, int size, int **newSize)
```

Or you can do using `int*` as below.

```
int newSize;
newArr = removeDuplicateElements(arr, size, &newSize);
size = newSize;
```

Comment: IMO only the part after _"Or you can do using `int*` as below."_ makes sense here.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @Jabberwocky, after reading the question's code only the last part is really what OP wants